# User confirmation mechanisim within database transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC. The user wants to save an entity into database. The entity itself has no problem for saving. But a field in the entity has a value that requires user to get notified. If the user accept the warning message, the entity will save, otherwise it is discarded. I wonder if spring has a straightforward mechanism to do so. If the answer is negative, is there any example that satisfy my condition?

> UPDATE

For example:

```
public void save(Entity object){
      if(object.getQuantity().equals(0)){
         /** get user confirmation and suspend here, if confirmed save the object, else return **/
      } else {
         super.save(object);
      }
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code, cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Please see the update section.

Comment: You are mixing concerns here. Getting user confirmation is a presentation layer responsibility and should be done before the object is saved to the DB in a transaction.